# How to find the maximum of this trigonometry expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization

> Given acute angles $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$$\dots$, $\alpha_n$ such that
> \[\sin^2\alpha_1+\sin^2\alpha_2+\dots+\sin^2\alpha_n=1,\]
> find the maximum of
> \[\frac{\sin\alpha_1+\sin\alpha_2+\dots+\sin\alpha_n}{\cos\alpha_1+\cos\alpha_2+\dots+\cos\alpha_n}.\]

I tried the equal variable theorem, where we needed $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to be strictly convex, but it is actually strictly concave. So we can not apply the theorem.

However, to find the answer, I still assumed $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots=\alpha_{n-1}$, and got the answer $\frac1{\sqrt{n-1}}$.

Comment: 1) Could you give a reference to the "equal variable theorem" that I don't know, at least under this name ? 2) Have you attempted to write a simulation program in order to have an idea of the optimum value you are looking for, at least for small values of $n$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie https://emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06_www.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie In addition, I used the `NMaximize` function in Mathematica on small $n$ and found that the equality case should be $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots=\alpha_n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $(x_1,\dots, x_n)=(\sin a_1, \dots, \sin a_n)$. Notice that $$\cos a_j = \left(\sum_{i\neq j} x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$

By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, for any real numbers $z_1, \dots, z_m$, we have
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m z_i^2\right)^{1/2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \sum_{i=1}^m z_i$$

Using the above facts we have
$$\cos a_1 + \dots+ \cos a_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i\neq j}x_i^2\right)^{1/2} \geq \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\sum_{i\neq j}x_i\right)=\sqrt{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

The last inequality gives the upper bound $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ which is also achieved when $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n$, and thus is the maximum value.